# How is VAT calculated on a car when I move to Ireland

Tags: ireland

When I move to Ireland this year I will have to pay VAT on my car that I am taking with me. How is the VAT of 21% calculated? Is it on the cost of the car when I bought it second hand or the cost of the car when it was new? Also as I have owned the car for more than 6 months will I need to pay the VRT?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have had your car for over 6 months, you may be freed from the VRT (Vehicle Registration Tax).

Since you are **transferring residence to the EU**, you may also be freed from VAT and customs duties for household goods (including **private cars**).

Follow the links found in the first link below, which go into detail about the exact conditions.

I found no information on how the VAT is actually calculated.

For VRT there is information on how it is calculated in the first link.

---

**Sources**:

- [Importing a vehicle into Ireland](https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_to_ireland/coming_to_live_in_ireland/importing_car_into_ireland.html)

  - [Transfer of residence (TOR)](https://www.revenue.ie/en/importing-vehicles-duty-free-allowances/guide-to-vrt/reliefs-and-exemptions/transfer-of-residence.aspx)

    - [Relief from Customs Duty and VAT on transferring residence to the EU](https://www.revenue.ie/en/importing-vehicles-duty-free-allowances/transfer-of-residence/index.aspx)